# Images are not getting downloaded using promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I need to download all images and generate word document with them.
Using nodeJS and Meteor

```js
WebApp.connectHandlers.use('/download', async function (req, res, next) {
  // ...

  const images = [];

  await lines.forEach(async (line, k) => {
    if (line.type && line.type === 'image') {
      images.push({
        id: line.id,
        file: line.id + '.jpg',
      });

      download_image(line.imageUrl, line.id + '.jpg');
    }
  });

  // ...

  // Then I use images[] to insert them into a Word document.
});

const download_image = (url, image_path) =>
  axios({
    url,
    responseType: 'stream',
  }).then(
    (response) =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        response.data
          .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(image_path))
          .on('finish', () => resolve())
          .on('error', (e) => reject(e));
      })
  );
```

The problem is images are not getting downloaded before I insert the into a Word document.

How to stop/await before images are finished to be downloaded? I am not so good with promises. What is missing her?

Thanks!

Comment: Look into [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its common mistake to use `.forEach` (or similar array methods) with `async` function inside it. The `async function` just mean that it returns promise and the `await` works in a same way like chaining together promises with `then`. Therefore this line `wait lines.forEach(async (line, k) => {` will just create and return bunch of promises, but it will not wait for all the promises inside to finish.

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use('/download', async function (req, res, next) {
  // ...

  const images = [];
  const promises = [];
  lines.forEach((line, k) => {
    if (line.type && line.type === 'image') {
      images.push({
        id: line.id,
        file: line.id + '.jpg',
      });

      promises.push(download_image(line.imageUrl, line.id + '.jpg'));
    }
  });
  // here you get array with all the images downloaded
  const downloadedImages = await Promise.all(promises);
  // this line will be executed after you download all images

  // ...
});

// This function would work same with or without the `async` keyword 
// (because async function return promise - you are returning the promise. 
// Async function allows to use await, but you are not using await in this function).
// However it is good practice to have all functions that returns promise 
// marked as `async` so you know that you receive promise from it.
const download_image = async (url, image_path) =>
  // Dont forget to return your promise otherwise you cannot await it
  return axios({
    url,
    responseType: 'stream',
  }).then(
    (response) =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        response.data
          .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(image_path))
          .on('finish', () => resolve())
          .on('error', (e) => reject(e));
      })
  );
```